# Django Admin Form Validation from QuerySet

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I have these two models:

```
class Service(MelosModel):
    performer = models.ForeignKey(Performer)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition)


class Event(MelosModel):
    event_type = models.ForeignKey('EventType')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    works = models.ManyToManyField(Work)
    date_of_event = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

*Note: A `MelosModel` is for all intents and purposes the same as `models.Model`. Also, `Composition` extends `Work`.*

The trouble is that the list of compositions in the `Service` admin form needs to be validated against the available `Work`s from its `Event.` How do you do this?

I read about making a `ModelChoiceField` from a queryset but that wouldn't help because we don't know what the `Event` is until the form is submitted. What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could write a [clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) on you Service model class to do the custom validation.

Comment: That definitely works. But I still worry that I'm not doing this correctly. To me, it would be a better database design to let the services set determine which works exist for an event, but that obviously doesn't help with validation.